# Checkbox checked in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML part:

```
 <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_1" value="john" emp-id="john">
 <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_2" value="john" emp-id="jim">
 <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_3" value="john" emp-id="sam">
 <input type="radio" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_4" value="john" emp-id="George">
```

I want to compare value and emp-id and if it is true, i need the checkbox to be checked so that checkbox will be displayed in the frontend as checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the HTML to use checkboxes:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_1" value="john" emp-id="john">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_2" value="john" emp-id="jim">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_3" value="john" emp-id="sam">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1"  id="checkbox_4" value="john" emp-id="George">
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='checkbox_1']").each(function(i,e){
       var el = $(this);
        this.checked = el.attr("emp-id") == el.val();
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MFpUQ/3/

Comment: I want to load on the page initially not when clicked on the checkbox

Comment: I want the checkbox to be checked when i visit the page itself..Now, when i click on the particular button it shows checked..but i need without the clicking..\

Comment: thanks..it worked. I need to know whether we can make this to work in select option so that if it is true the select option will display it automatically..

Comment: Here is the fiddleof what i need http://jsfiddle.net/STk7k/ . I want to compare the emp-id and value. It it is true i need the answer to be shown on select option automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter radios:

```
$(':radio').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr("emp-id") === this.value
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Wrap it inside document ready handler if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**html:**

```
<input type="radio" ... checked>
```

**javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("checkbox_3").checked=true;
```